# Why can't I create a junction with Dropbox?

Tags: windows, dropbox, junction, mklink

Had to relink my Dropbox after some problems and realized that my old Dropbox folder is "My Dropbox" and the new is "Dropbox". I went ahead and renamed the folder so I wouldn't have to download all of my files over and it merged nicely, taking forever to index though.

The problem now is that tons of program configurations and shortcuts are broken after the rename so I need to create a junction. However, this is what happens:

> C:>mklink /J "C:\Users\Craig\My Dropbox" "C:\Users\Craig\Dropbox"
>
> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

What can I do?

Comment: What is the output of the command `dir C:\Users\Craig` ? Does it contain an entry for "My Dropbox" ?

Answer (score 1):

When Creating a Junction the initial Folder cannot exist 
`"C:\Users\Craig\My Dropbox"`
mklink likes to create this itself

Very useful information on understanding mklink http://www.maxi-pedia.com/mklink